# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream on using HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to implement reading from .xls file. I have the following code:

```
FileInputStream file = null;
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/" + fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (fileName.endsWith(".xls")) {
        try {
            **workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);**
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This marked code line crashes.

I imported in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but I got the error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream

I would appreciate help on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: So I must not understand something about Maven and dependencies. How as POI package built without this dependency in its pom.xml?

Comment: as David mentions: I had only the poi-ooxml dependency when working with Java17. After upgrading to Java21, I also needed to add the commons-io 2.15.0 in order to prevent OP's mentioned exception when generating a new XSSFWorkBook

Answer (score 7):

I recently upgraded Apache POI to 5.2.3 and was having the same ClassNotFoundException. Since the application was working fine before the upgrade, so I quickly did three things to debug:

1. Search on stackoverflow.com ;-)
2. Check to see from what version of Apache Commons IO has the
   org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
   class. ***In the JavaDoc, it was since 2.7.***
3. Check my maven dependency tree to find out what version of the Apache Commons IO I am using. ***Turns
   out the commons-io I had was 2.2 and it was from the
   commons-fileupload 1.4 in my maven pom.xml***

Once I added the latest available Apache Commons IO 2.11.0 to my maven pom.xml and rebuild the application, the problem solved. I hope this help!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

to you pom

Comment: I get same error. But when I use latest version 2.11.0, then I got this error: org.apache.poi.hssf.OldExcelFormatException: The supplied spreadsheet seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8 format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)

Comment: I used OldExcelExtractor.

Comment: fixed the error by specifying a newer version of commons-io

Answer (score 4):

Change the dependency to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I used the version 5.2.0 as well and was getting the same error and changing that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have commons-io dependency. please add this dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I read excel to XSSFWorkbook, it prompt error message that "commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream" finally fixed it by downgrad the version of poi from 5.2.3 to 5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by removing this dependency

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved with following dependencies:
[Dependencies]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```